# Webpack production process.env.PORT=undefined on server compile (React app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, build

I have my React app compiling all fine in dev & prod scripts, however, now that I am deploying on DigitalOcean, I am running into a problem with `process.env.port` being `undefined` and therefore falling back to `3000` and not the expected port `80`.

Package.json npm script:

`"build": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.production.js && 
    cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/server.js"`

Webpack.config.production.js script which includes the DefinePlugin() for process.env:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ["./src/scripts/index.js"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name]-bundle.js", path: __dirname, publicPath: "/"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          {loader: "style-loader"}, {
            loader: "css-loader"}, {
            loader: "sass-loader"}, {
            loader: "postcss-loader"}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[path][name].[ext]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env": {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
  }
}),
extractSass,
new UglifyJsPlugin({
  sourceMap: true,
  uglifyOptions: {
    output: {
      comments: false
    }
  }
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: "public/index.html",
  favicon: "public/assets/img/favicon.ico"
}),
new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: "styles/styles.css",
  allChunks: true
})
]
};
```

my express server file:

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

let useFolder;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  useFolder = "/public/";
  const webpack = require("webpack");
  const config = require("../webpack.config.development");
  const compiler = webpack(config);
  app.use(
    require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
      noInfo: true,
      publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
      hot: true
    })
  );
  app.use(
    require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler, {
      log: console.log,
      path: "/__webpack_hmr",
      heartbeat: 10 * 1000
    })
  );
} else {
  useFolder = "/dist/";
}
app.use(express.static("dist"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, ".." + useFolder + "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log("Listening at port: ", port);
});
```

There are no errors, and when it runs on backup port `3000` all is good on the live server, but I am expecting port 80.

I have tried swapping where `NODE_ENV=production` gets set: removing from NPM script, and DefinePlugin() but no success either.

Answer (score 3):

Webpack will by default bundle for web. This means it will replace all `process.env.` statements with what you have defined in the DefinePlugin. You never set `PORT` to anything, so it will be undefined.
You have two options, either define `PORT` in the DefinePlugin, or change the webpack target to `node` and remove the DefinePlugin. This will make webpack use the actual environment variables on runtime.
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/

Answer (score 2):

To create environment variable within the project create a **.env** file at the root of the project and add values in that file. You may have to re-run the deployment script you have to bundle them all again. We normally comment values related to other environments during the deployment, we have a script to do that.

```
#dev
PORT=6000
URL=Blahhh.dev.com

#prod
PORT=7000
URL=Blahhh.com
```